# google java api for google search

Tags: java, api

Does google provide a Java server side api **(NOT java script).**I dont want the ajax api which works at clint side.
What i want is that the result returned for  a keyword should return me search result in some specific data structure.Like List or set data  structure.Then i want to manipulate the result according to my need in java code.
I had used such a java server site api for youtube.

Answer (score 2):

They [used to](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#gen1) but is [discontinued](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#gen8). Most likely because you can remove their ads ;-)

Comment: but i used such server side data api for youtube and it worked fine

Comment: from http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html#ini2 the SOAP API was meant for search only. YouTude, Docs, etc have different APIs not related to the Search API. Disclaimer: the part about the ads is a joke.

Answer (score 2):

From [Google's terms of service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/mobile/xhtml/terms_of_service.html)

> You may not send automated queries of any sort to Google's system
>   without express permission in advance from Google.

So, no - use their AJAX API. The [SAOP API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/) is discoutinued, but I think you should be able to use it, unless it requires a key, in which case you are tied to the AJAX API

Technically, the statement quoted above doesn't mean you *can't* use some sort of server-side API - there are examples of that if you google around. It means you *shouldn't* do it, because sooner or later you will be blacklisted (banned), as violating the terms.

Comment: but i used such server side data api for youtube and it worked fine

Comment: the terms may be different for youtube. Also, the text quoted above doesn't mean "you cannot". It means you should not, because you might get banned/blacklisted

Answer (score 1):

What you would be looking for now is the CustomSearch API:

They used to have a different API developers could use but it has been depreciated (Nov. 2009 I think) so this is a for cost service now.  I am not aware how long it might have been a free service.  The new API allows 100 free searches a day, but you have to be signed up for billing else anything above 100 searches will fail, here are the details:

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html

And sorry yes, this would still be using Java Script but you could use this:
http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 0):

There is at least a SOAP API that I'm aware of: [Google SOAP Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/api_faq.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Google wants 3rd parties to use their search engine for their own services/applications. You would get "we think you are a robot" error page as a result if Google thinks you are not a real person.

You can however try [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.co.uk/cse/)